# How to wrap every 3 posts in a div (and close the last div too)

Tags: php, loop

I have code that wraps every 3 posts in a div (so that the posts will line up horizontally even if different heights). It closes the div after 3 posts, but the problem is the div is left open if there aren't any more posts left but it ended with 1 or 2 in that div row. How can I close the last div?

```
    <?php
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php $i=1; ?>

    <?php
    /* Start the Loop */
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if($i==1 || $i%3==1) echo '<div class="row">' ;?>

        <div class="project">
        </div> <!-- /.project -->

    <?php if($i%3==0) echo '</div>' ;?>    

    <?php $i++;endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is purely PHP which is considered to be Off-topic but this is my take:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();
            $i = $wp_query->current_post;
            echo ( 0 == $i % 3 ) ? '<div class="row">' : '';
    ?>

        <div class="project">
        </div> <!-- /.project -->

    <?php
            echo ( $wp_query->post_count == $i || 2 == $i % 3 ) ? '</div>' : '';
        endwhile;
    ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The `$wp_query->current_post` is a built-in query property that stats at 0 and holds the index of the posts array.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) { 

    $i = 1;
    // Always start the list with a div.row 
    echo( '<div class="row">' );
    /* Start the Loop */
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();     
        if( $i%3 == 0 && $i != 1 ) {
            echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL . '<div class="row">';
        }
    ?>

    <div class="project">
    </div> <!-- /.project -->

<?php

    } // end of the while() loop
    // end the last div.row -- this will always execute if have_posts() is true
    echo( '</div>' ); 
} // end of the if( have_posts() ) conditional
```

**Note:** I haven't tested this code.